# How to close OleDbConnection from another class

Tags: c#, excel, oledb, oledbconnection, vba

I have an Excel file that is being connected to and used to read data from to complete a process

Here is the code:

```
    public void eConnection(string srcString, string id)
    {
        tmpArry = new ArrayList();
        GlobalTestFlow = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        StepData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        innerData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        setTestID(id);

        conString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="+srcString+"; Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;'";
        connection = new OleDbConnection(conString);
        connection.Open();

    }
```

I make the first connection using this and then read the Excel file using this code from another project that reference the original connection:

```
    public static string testID;
    public eDriver driver;
    private string conSrc = "'C:Desktop\\Test Data\\OLBBAppTestData.xlsx'";
    private string workSheet = "Global";


    public void OLBBFrinLnLoanTest()
    {
        testID = "1"; // Dynamic per test case generated

        driver = new eDriver();
        driver.eConnection(conSrc, testID); //Connection is made to Excel here 
        driver.getTestFlow(workSheet); //Grab the worksheet to read data from 

        foreach (string tmp in driver.GlobalTestFlow.Keys)
        {
            switch (driver.GlobalTestFlow[tmp].ToString())
            {

                case "OpenActivateLoan": //Find data that matches "OpenActivateLoan"
                    cOLBBOpenActivateLoan exeOpenActivateLoan = new cOLBBOpenActivateLoan();
                    exeOpenActivateLoan.StandAlone(driver, driver.GlobalTestFlow[tmp].ToString()); //Execute this once data matches 
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Once exeOpenActivateLoan is called, another class is called to continue the process:

```
    namespace OLBBv2.Components
    {
        class cOLBBOpenActivateLoan
        {
            private mOLBBOpenActivateLoan loanModule;

            internal void StandAlone(eDriver e, string worksheet)
            {
                e.getStepData(worksheet); //find step Data to continue workflow 
                loanModule = new mOLBBOpenActivateLoan();

                foreach (string tmp in e.StepData.Keys)
                {
                    switch (tmp)
                    {
                        case "i_ClickActionButton":
 //calling this function to insert back into Excel file, This is where I would like to close the original connection
                            loanModule._ClickSubmitButton();
                            break;

                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
                e.ResetStepData();
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to close the connection before the function is called because the function that is being called will update the Excel file

Here is the code that is being called to update the Excel File:

```
public void _InsertLoanActNumSegmentToExcel()
{
    eWriter writer = new eWriter();
            string loanAct = "applesauce";
            writer.insertToDataSheet(loanAct);
}
```

In eWrirter class I establish a new connection to the Excel file to write to it:

```
      public void insertToDataSheet(string loanAct)
            {
                try
                {
                    string srcExcel = "C:\\Test Data\\OLBBAppTestData.xlsx";

                    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection MyConnection;
                    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand myCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand();
                    string sql = null;
                    MyConnection = new OleDbConnection("Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = " + srcExcel + "; Extended Properties = 'Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;'");
                    MyConnection.Open();

                    myCommand.Connection = MyConnection;

                    sql = "UPDATE [Global$] SET o_AccountNumber ='"+loanAct+"' WHERE TestID='"+getTestID()+"'";

                    myCommand.CommandText = sql;

//Exception gets thrown here with error message "Operation must use an updateable query"
                    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
                    MessageBox.Show("Insert Success!");
                    MyConnection.Close();

                }
                catch (Exception eInnerData)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Method: getInnerData " + eInnerData.ToString());
                }
            }
```

After trying to execute the query, I get an error because the connection is still opened from when I was reading the data, I want to close the connection, then reopen it to insert back into the Excel File

What I am trying to do is read from the Excel file, then update the Excel file on a new connection

Comment: You shouldn't do it like this. Use a local (meaning, local for a method) variable for your `OleDbConnection` instance inside a `using` statement. `DbConnection` is an `IDisposable` and so are all the classes that inherits from it, `OleDbConnection` included.

Comment: I want to add to @ZoharPeled that `using` is transformed by compiler into `try...finally` where in `finally` a connection is closed and disposed.